# Running thermometer-test Bluez 5.18 dbus error

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I need to develop an application with a bluetooth dongle that makes use of the thermometer profile. The thing is that, after succesfully pair and connect with the remote device, whenever I try to run the `test-therometer` file, I obtain the following error:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "RegisterWatcher" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.ThermometerManager1" doesn't exist
```

I have also tested the `test-heartrate`, and I obtain something similar:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "RegisterWatcher" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.HeartRateManager1" doesn't exist
```

I have successfully tested the dongle with bluetoothctl, so I can discard hardware compatibility issues. I'd like to know if I'm missing something while running the tests.

I'm working under ArchLinux x86_64.

Comment: Can you run [D-Feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DFeet?action=show&redirect=DFeet) or similar DBus debugger under arch? Or could be that the method is looking for a variant not a string. That's pure speculation though.

Comment: could you solve your issue? also, which termometer are you using for your work?

Comment: At the end I couldn't run the the example until I used `bluetoothctl` command to pair and connect. Also, I think I needed to modify a bit the code in test-thermometer and allow the normal user to manage the Dbus that the profile uses. Finally, I crafted a Python script mixing `test-adapter, test-discovery and test-device` that managed the connection, and another one based on `test-thermometer` for the application. Just for the record, I didn't manage to run the test-heartrate.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the information. BTW, which thermometer were you using for your test (make/model)?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and am stuck at the same place. I can use gatttool to get heart rate readings from the device.  I can pair in bluetoothctl. But I still have the error
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "RegisterWatcher" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.HeartRateManager1" doesn't exist
At the moment I'm stumped.